Access gitlab webhook payload outside defined variable (e.g. project_id) using gitlab plugin for jenkins
The gitlab plugin provides some defined variables, but the variables that i want (project_id) is not defined. Is there a way to access the whole payload?
I tried printing the whole environment variable using printenv, but there's no json payload.
